# Setting list of files as alias to POSIX

Tags: applescript

I'm new to applescript and have been trying to select multiple files (or a folder if it's easier) and return the path in posix file format.  With the end goal of running a vba macro on each file selected.  All of the answers that seem to have dealt with this are from when macscript wasn't deprecated.  I have gotten the below to return as a POSIX file when only one file is selected, otherwise only one path is shown.  I tried to get around that by incrementally adding each change to a list, but that seems to break the conversion to POSIX.

```
on select_files()
    set filelist to {}
    set CSV_files to choose file with prompt "Pick CSV Files to convert" with multiple selections allowed
    
    --tell application "System Events"
    --set C_path to POSIX path of CSV_files
    --end tell
    
    repeat with a in CSV_files
        convertPathToPOSIXString(a)
        --InsertItemInList(a, filelist, -1)
    end repeat
end select_files

select_files()


on convertPathToPOSIXString(thePath)
    tell application "System Events"
        try
            set thePath to path of disk item (thePath as string)
        on error
            set thePath to path of thePath
        end try
    end tell
    return POSIX path of thePath
end convertPathToPOSIXString
```

I've edited out other methods I've tried that haven't worked.  Both convertPathToPOSIXString and InsertItemInList were taken from the mac automation scripting guide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`System Events` is not needed. You can get the POSIX path of an `alias` specifier directly

Append each POSIX path to `filelist` and return `filelist`

```
on select_files()
    set filelist to {}
    set CSV_files to choose file with prompt "Pick CSV Files to convert" with multiple selections allowed
    
    repeat with a in CSV_files
        set end of filelist to POSIX path of a
    end repeat
    return filelist
end select_files

select_files()
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to delegate the work to System Events. With the **Posix path** command of Standard Additions, this is easier and faster.

Also, it is not necessary to create an additional (new) list. Everything can be converted directly in the existing list.

```
on select_files()
    set CSV_files to choose file with prompt "Pick CSV Files to convert" with multiple selections allowed
    repeat with anItem in CSV_files
        set contents of anItem to POSIX path of anItem
    end repeat
    return CSV_files
end select_files

select_files()
```